# netty-4.x Using an attachment

Tags: netty

The 4.0 documentation for [ChannelHandler](http://static.netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/channel/ChannelHandler.html) offers get/set Attachment as a state management option. They do not appear to be implemented. Will they be implemented, or what is the suggested alternative. **Note:** A member variable is not an option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the Channel.attr(..) method.

See:
http://netty.io/4.0/api/io/netty/util/AttributeMap.html

Comment: Thanks, this works well. Hopefully it will make it into the  ChannelHandler documentation.